# syntax for SOCKS proxy in apt.conf

Tags: apt, proxy

I want to add SOCKS proxy settings to /etc/apt/apt.conf. What is the syntax for it? Is it same as http and ftp syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A possible solution can be to use `tsocks`, an application that can redirect the network traffic through a socks proxy.
Install `tsocks` package, modify `/etc/tsocks.conf` to set address and port number of your socks proxy, and run:

```
$ sudo -s
# tsocks apt-get update
# tsocks apt-get dist-upgrade
# exit
$
```

or

```
$ sudo -s
# . tsocks -on
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# . tsocks -off # not really necessary, given the exit
# exit
$
```

You can think to a number of options, to simplify and automate its use.

Don't forget the leading dot, the [Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/tsocks.1.html) has more deatails on this.

**Edit**: a shorter way to use it:

```
$ sudo tsocks apt-get update
$ sudo tsocks apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: It seems tsocks is not installed by default, so I need to run `sudo tsocks apt-get install tsocks`. Hahahahahaha...

Comment: You can use curl to download `tsocks`, install it and then use :)

Comment: Also: As of apt 1.3~rc1 (Debian version, not sure exactly which Ubuntu version, though my guess is not until Zesty), you can use `Acquire::http::Proxy "socks5h://hostname:port/"`.  See the changelog at https://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=apt/apt.git;a=blob;f=debian/changelog;hb=f5e9be1da89725f9bf1915bdf86fdc4a77edf917

Comment: Well... that's funny. To make apt-get work you need to... `apt-get something`!

Comment: a little correction to @derobert line: `Acquire::socks::Proxy "socks5h://hostname:port/";` does the trick. Http does **not** - try it with Tor and you'll see  a standard response "Tor is not a http proxy", so the `http` goes replaced by `socks` - and it works!

Answer (score 68):

```
Acquire::http::proxy "socks5h://server:port";
```

This works for me on Ubuntu 18.04.
As the man page says, socks5h, not socks5, is supported by apt, which means socks5 proxy with DNS resolving ability.

Comment: This is correct and indeed seems to work on Ubuntu 18.04. Although one might want to include _Acquire::https::proxy_ and _Acquire::ftp::proxy_ as well (with the same value).

Comment: adding proxy rule `Acquire::https::proxy "socks5h://server:port";` to a `apt.conf.d` file (like `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/12proxy`) works just fine. I would suggest to stick to **https** unless otherwise is necessary.

Comment: Also for a proxy server requiring authentication, this line is modified as `Acquire::http::proxy "socks5h://user:pass@server:port";`. The above rule works just fine in Ubuntu 18.04. Here `socks5h` enforces DNS resolution at the proxy server.

Comment: Anyone knows if this works in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: doesn't work on 14.04

Comment: (the option name itself is case insensitive, so you can type `acquire::http::proxy`)

Comment: I wonder what needs to be done on Debian to make it work too?

Answer (score 12):

Using the next config line works for me:

```
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks5://server:port";
```

To keep `apt.conf` clean and avoid problems at Linux upgrade I created a new file (`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/12proxy`) and added the config file to it.

Comment: what's the begin number mean in the foler

Comment: It's just the script execution order

Comment: This is wrong. This doesn't work.

Comment: What failed to you @dedunumax? Any error? Any clue?

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: It should be Acquire::http::proxy and also socks5**h** for dns resolution on proxy side

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find anything on **Acquire::socks::proxy** in the apt.conf manual of Ubuntu Xenial. You could fix this by running a local http proxy that supports upstream socks proxy, for example Polipo. You need to configure Polipo as follows:

```
proxyAddress = "::1"
proxyPort = 8118
socksParentProxy = "sockshost:socksport"
socksProxyType = socks5
```

and then set the http proxy in your apt.conf file:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8118/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://127.0.0.1:8118/";
```

Comment: This is a great solution, it worked for me smoothly on Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Or tou can put in your /etc/apt/apt.conf something like this:

```
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://user:pass@host:port/";
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Works in 13.10.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is wrong syntax, it means "proxy all URLs that begin with socks:// through socks://user:pass@host:port/".  Really, it should be this: `Acquire::http::proxy "socks://user:pass@host:port/";`

Comment: @Hans-ChristophSteiner: This makes a connection to the indicated host and port, but the connection does not use the socks protocol.  It looks like a http proxy protocol, but I did not check with an actual http proxy.

Comment: At this point, I'm sure that `Acquire::socks` is for setting the proxy for URLs that start with `socks://`.  So that means you don't need a proxy to access the internet, and `apt` is not using any proxy for `ftp://`, `http://`, or `https://`..  `apt` only supports HTTP proxies, i.e. `Acquire::http::proxy "http://localhost:8118`.

Answer (score 3):

In Debian, you can read the manpage `apt-transport-http(1)` and look for supported URI schemes. As was answered before, put

```
Acquire::http::proxy "socks5h://server:port";
```

in

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/12proxy
```

You can read more about the APT-config in general in `apt.conf(5)` and read the examples in `/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index.gz` mentioned at the end of the manpage.

This can be combined with `ssh -D <LOCAL PORT> <USER>@<HOST>` to create a SOCKS proxy to a different system so that apt can then use the proxy as if everything originated on `<HOST>`.

If you use `ssh -D 0.0.0.0:<LOCAL PORT> <USER>@<HOST>` or `ssh -D [::]:<LOCAL PORT> <USER>@<HOST>` (for IPv6) to enable other systems to use the SOCKS proxy on **all** interfaces. **This can be a security risk or breach of (corporate) policy. Make sure you know what you are doing.**