# How to use TOR SOCKS proxy for apt-get?

Tags: apt, proxy, tor, socks5

I am running tor browser in my Ubuntu 14.04 and and after successful connection I used socks proxy which is **127:0.0.1:9150** in my browser and it worked fine. But when I put **Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://127.0.0.1:9150/";** in apt.conf it's not working at all. How can I use apt-get with socks? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: The [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/apt.conf.5.html) for apt.conf doesn't list a socks option. Try http://askubuntu.com/q/35223/158442

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you install the package `apt-transport-tor`. This allows you to download packages anonymously.